# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 Google AdMob in Version 6.7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, libraries, arm64

Okay so google AdMob API is supposed to work now for arm64, but I am getting this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)
objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADGestureIdUtil.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've searched on Google and many people suggest to avoid using 64Bit capabilities. But now the API is supposed to work so I don't see why I should do that.

I am really stucked here.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer so that you can accept it; that way the question will no longer show up as “unanswered”.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Okay so I found the solution.**

Google guide iOS developers on how to implement AdMob SDK, however they are missing some info. They tell you it's mandatory to add these Frameworks:

```
   - AudioToolbox.Framework
   - MessageUI.Framework
   - SystemConfiguration.Framework
   - CoreGraphics.Framework
```

To solve the error I added this ones also:

```
   -CoreData.Framework
   -AdSupport.Framework
   -CoreTelephony.Framework
```

Comment: On github CocoaPods for Google Mobile Ads SDK you can check the json files for each version to ensure you've added all: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/5/9/a/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK

Answer (score 3):

Along with **-CoreData.Framework** and **-AdSupport.Framework** I also found that I had to add the **-CoreTelephony.framework** in order to get a clean build of the sample app that is provided.  (Banner Example)

Answer (score 3):

The Google Mobile Ads SDK library references the following iOS development frameworks which may not already be part of your project:

- AdSupport
- AudioToolbox
- AVFoundation
- CoreGraphics
- CoreTelephony
- MessageUI
- StoreKit
- SystemConfiguration

Make sure all of them are added to your target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries.

[More info](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios)

Answer (score 0):

along with all these

- AdSupport
- AudioToolbox
- AVFoundation
- CoreGraphics
- CoreTelephony
- MessageUI
- StoreKit
- SystemConfiguration

I had to add CoreMotion as well.